# How to use Watchtower with ECS Fargate?

Tags: aws-fargate, docker-watchtower, watchtower

I'm trying to use watchtower on ECS Fargate. But the documentation says watchtower must bind to /var/run/docker.sock. But AFAIK ECS Fargate doesn't support that.

Is there a way to use watchtower with AWS Fargate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't map the Docker socket in Fargate. You need to build a simple Pipeline that checks for new container images and redeploy an ECS/Fargate service when it detects a new image.

This is a good [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/automatically-deploying-your-container-application-with-aws-copilot/) if you want to go down this route.